# How to change structure of an array so it can be used in simple_calendar gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm using viewpoint gem to get appointments from an exchange server.
This is what I get from the server:

```
arr = [{:elems=>[
   {:start_time=>{:text=>"2023-02-17T08:00:00"}},
   {:end_time=>{:text=>"2023-02-17T10:00:00"}},
   {:busy_type=>{:text=>"Busy"}}
  ]
 },
 {:elems=>[
   {:start_time=>{:text=>"2023-02-18T02:00:00"}},
   {:end_time=>{:text=>"2023-02-18T03:00:00"}},
   {:busy_type=>{:text=>"Busy"}}
  ]
 }
]
```

How can I change the structure of this array so I can pass it as an event to simple_calendar gem

I think it should be like this:

```
[[2023-02-18T08:00:00], [2023-02-18T02:00:00]]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you

Comment: Can you update the complete required output?

Comment: In editing your question I have made an assumption about what you are looking for. Please edit if I am wrong. When giving an example always show the desired result as a complete, valid Ruby object (e.g., no "....").

Comment: In editing I assigned your given array to a variable (`arr`). By doing so readers can refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to reproduce the entire array. See, for example, my answer. In general, when giving examples it's helpful to assign a variable to each input object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made the assumptions that

- the elements of each array are hashes;
- the values of each hash are arrays or hashes;
- if the value of a hash is a hash the later has a single key; and
- if the values of a hash are hashes the latter is to be replaced by the value of the only key in the hash.

If these assumptions are satisfied the desired result can be obtain with the following recursive method.

```
def recurse(obj)
  case obj
  when Array
    obj.map { |hash| recurse(hash) }
  else # Hash
    obj.transform_values do |o|
      case o
      when Array
        recurse(o)
      else # Hash
        o.values.first
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Let's try it.

```
recurse arr
  #=> [
  #    {:elems=>[
  #      {:start_time=>"2023-02-17T08:00:00"},
  #      {:end_time=>"2023-02-17T10:00:00"},
  #      {:busy_type=>"Busy"}
  #     ]
  #    },
  #    {:elems=>[
  #      {:start_time=>"2023-02-18T02:00:00"},
  #      {:end_time=>"2023-02-18T03:00:00"},
  #      {:busy_type=>"Busy"}
  #     ]
  #    }
  #   ]
```

Comment: Thanks Cary is exactly what I thought I want but can it be transformed in a hash ? I'm trying to use this array in `simple_calendar gem` so that the events are displayed on each day. But i get this:   `undefined method `start_time' for [{:start_time=>"2023-02-21T02:00:00"}, {:end_time=>"2023-02-21T02:30:00"}, {:busy_type=>"Busy"}]:Array`

       ` events = options.fetch(:events, []).reject { |e| e.send(attribute).nil? }.sort_by(&attribute)` this means It needs a hash i believe like an instance of a record called from the database.

Comment: What is your desired hash for the given example? Note that I am unfamiliar with that gem.

Comment: Hi Cary the docs for the simple_calendar gem say create :```# multi-day events
$ rails g scaffold Meeting name start_time:datetime end_time:datetime``` and then setup ```def index
  # Scope your query to the dates being shown:
  start_date = params.fetch(:start_date, Date.today).to_date
  @meetings = Meeting.where(starts_at: start_date.beginning_of_month.beginning_of_week..start_date.end_of_month.end_of_week)
end```  but I can skip this because my data is all ready setup between today and and today +10.days . So my date needs to be setup as a model that comes from database i presume

Comment: Sorry, but being unfamiliar with that gem (and with Rails, in fact), I don't think I can be of further help. Perhaps a reader could take it from here.